# JavaScript - concat two numbers and treat the result as a number

Tags: javascript

here's the code I'm struggling with. I'd like to concat the two inputs together and keep the result as an integer (number in JS's case).

```
var secsVal = -1;
function valueAssign(i) {

    if (secsVal == -1){

        document.getElementById("countdown").value = i;
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = (i);

        secsVal = i;
    }
    else {      
        secsVal = "" + secsVal + i;//concatenating first value of i to the second.
        secsVal = secsVal.map(Number);//trying to convert back to num, but I think map() needs to see an array, which I don't think I got here.

        document.getElementById("countdown").value = secsVal;
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = (secsVal);//I want to replace the first displayed digit here, with the new (concatenated) number.
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirements. In HTML all you can store is text (not JavaScript data types like numbers or dates).

Comment: There's no need to convert back to a number.

Comment: You mean something like `Number(1 + '' + '2')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to use a number for a value in an input tag. The type is always a string.

To convert to number use either `Number` or an unary `+`

```
secsVal = Number(secsVal);
```

or

```
secsVal = +secsVal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
secsVal = +("" + secsVal + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
secsVal = Number('' + secsVal + i)   // explicit cast to number
secsVal = +('' + secsVal + i)        // implicit cast to number
secsVal = parseInt('' + secsVal + i) // explicit cast to integer
secsVal = ~~('' + secsVal + i)       // implicit cast to integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `+secsVal`

```js
var secsVal = -1;
function valueAssign(i) {

    if (secsVal == -1){

        document.getElementById("countdown").value = i;
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = (i);

        secsVal = i;
    }
    else {      
        secsVal = "" + secsVal + i;
        console.log(typeof secsVal);//secsVal is a string
        
        secsVal = +secsVal;
        console.log(typeof secsVal); //secsVal is now a number

        document.getElementById("countdown").value = secsVal;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="countdown"/>
<button onclick="valueAssign(5)">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about parsing the String?

"The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer."
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp